# The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num', even if I check if the value is not null

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have this function:

```
double discount() {
    return cost_min_discounted != null ? cost_min - cost_min_discounted : 0;
}
```

`cost_min_discounted` is defined as `double?`
I get the error:

> The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'num'

What's the best way to write code like that? I check for the null value, so the code seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've already checking null at beginning, use `!` at the end.

```dart
double discount() {
  return cost_min_discounted != null ? cost_min - cost_min_discounted! : 0;
}
```

Comment: Since it is a class field it can theoretically change between your check and the usage. In a multithreaded application this can be a really hard bug to track down. Assigning to a local variable first guarantees it will never be null when used.

Comment: What about `return cost_min - (cost_min_discounted ?? 0)`

Comment: @DanHarms as it already checked the null value, I can't see any possibility to get it null and throw the error, It will return the right expression on null cases.

Comment: @GiacomoM yes it will return `cost_min` if `cost_min_discounted`  becomes null.

Comment: Another thread can change the value. There's a reason you have to add the bang to the use because it's not guaranteed non-null there.